# IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.sun.media.sound.JSSecurity error

Tags: java, audio

I'm simply trying to use the method `getAudioInputStream(file)` from the class `AudioSystem`, but I got the following exception:

```
IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.sun.media.sound.JSSecurity from class com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader at
```

class com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(unknown source)

I can not figure out where the problem is. Is it a problem with libraries?

Comment: That'll be an implementation class you are not supposed to be using. May well have changed in an update release.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. Which class are you taking about? AudioSystem?

Comment: I just found out that the class SoftMidiAudioFileReader is missing from the package com.sun.media.sound of my JRE system libraries.